# How should i increase the score variable in my python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, variables, compiler-errors

```py
from turtle import Turtle

SCORE=0

class Scoreboard(Turtle):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.color("white")
        self.up()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.goto(-10,290)
        self.write(f"score : {SCORE} ",align="center",font=("Arial",16,"normal"))
    

    def score_change(self):
        SCORE+=1
        self.__init__()'''
```

I am new to this python.I want to increase the SCORE variable when i call the method from main.py but i am getting error like local variable 'SCORE' referenced before assignment.I know some posts are there with this error but i want to find the solution for this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the `global` keyword before `SCORE` in the function as `SCORE` is a **global variable**. So when you do `SCORE += 1` then `SCORE` is not found as in python you need to explicitly tell `global` to access **variables not encapsulated** in **class** else they are interpreted as **static members of class** as in your case.

Change you method as below

```
def score_change(self):
    global SCORE # add this line
    SCORE += 1
    self.__init__()
```

Corrected source:

```
from turtle import Turtle

SCORE = 0


class Scoreboard(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.color("white")
        self.up()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.goto(-10,290)
        self.write(f"score : {SCORE} ",align="center",font=("Arial",16,"normal"))

    def score_change(self):
        global SCORE
        SCORE += 1
        self.__init__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = Scoreboard()
    src.score_change()
    src.score_change()
    src.score_change()
    print(SCORE)


# Output:
3
```

Also i would suggest if the SCORE is only used in the context if the Scoreboard Class then you should make it a static member as below and change the `def score_change()` method as it was previous. And access the `SCORE` how we access static members. like `Scoreboard.SCORE`

my Suggestion Source:

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Scoreboard(Turtle):
    SCORE = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.color("white")
        self.up()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.goto(-10,290)
        self.write(f"score : {Scoreboard.SCORE} ",align="center",font=("Arial",16,"normal"))

    def score_change(self):
        Scoreboard.SCORE += 1
        self.__init__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = Scoreboard()
    src.score_change()
    src.score_change()
    src.score_change()
    src.score_change()
    src.score_change()
    print(Scoreboard.SCORE)
```